# importing home.js into react-native app.js fails with error cannot resolve home.js

Tags: react-native, screen, custom-font

I am building a react-native app with a screen home.js file in `screens/home.js` folder by importing
with import Home from `./screens/home.js`; in App.js
iam using expo cli
when i run expo start --web
error occurs cannot resolve `./screens/home.js`. iam sure with the path and file name. what can be the problem

App.js

```
 import React ,{useState}from 'react';
    //import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
    import Home from './screens/home';
    import * as font from 'expo-font';
    import {AppLoaded} from 'expo';

    const getFonts=()=>{
      return Font.loadASync({
       'nunito-regular':require('./assets/fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf'),
       'nunito-bold':require('./assets/fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf'),
      })

    }

    export default function App() {
      const [fontsLoaded,setFontsLoaded]=useState(false);  
       if(fontsLoaded){
          return(
            <Home/>
          );
        }
        else{
          return(
            < AppLoaded 
            startASync={getFonts}
            onFinish={()=>setFontsLoaded(true)}
            />
          )
        }
    }
```

screens/home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default function Home() {
  render(){
     return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Home Screen</Text>
         </View> 
  );
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding:24,
  },
  titleText:{
    fontFamily:'nunito-bold',
    fontSize:18,
  }
});
```

Comment: The thing here is you cannot use render in functional component try to remove render() than check it

Answer (score 1):

Remove render method from the home screen made some changes to your code try to do some thing like this:

```
import React ,{useState}from 'react';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import * as font from 'expo-font';
import {AppLoaded} from 'expo';


export default function App() {
    return(
        <Home/>
    ) 
}
```

And home.js to

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';


export default function Home() {

     return (
        <View style={{justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center",flex:1}}>
            <Text >Home Screen</Text>
         </View> 
  );
}
```